# Error in android application testing

Tags: android

Why i am getting following error while testing the application? `App1 does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml`

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/healthdiary" android:label="@string/app_name">  
     <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
             android:targetPackage="HealthDiary1"
             android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
    <activity android:name=".HealthDiary"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Is this coming when your running your application, or running test project

Comment: i am getting this error while i am testing my project using Run->Android JUnit Test from main menu of eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare all your activities and services in android manifest file

here's the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I know reading the documentation is boring, but it always helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified) question?

One of the answers says you are probably missing the following in your manifest.

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="your.package"
    android:label="your tests label" />
```

and

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Comment: yes i looked at it and also inserted this lines with appropriate changes in my AndroidManifest.xml file. but i am not getting where i am going wrong?

Comment: Post your code showing where you have done this, because something is not setup correctly in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

For you that like me was searching for a solution and didn't found easily, is that:

> Right click on your project name in the Project Explorer (for you who
>   are using Eclipse) and select Run As > Android application.

Just.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Link :

[Android Eclipse Plugin: Instrumentation Test Runner not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified)

You're probably missing the following in your AndroidManifest.xml:

Hope it helps

Comment: After seeing your code, i found that targetpackage i.e., android:targetPackage="HealthDiary1" is wrong because package should be of form "your.package" not a single word right.

Comment: Package name must have at least two identifiers like example "com.HealthDiary1", you would have done right while creating application test runner

Answer (score 0):

Try run it from

right click -> run as -> android application

It worked for me (my manifest was okay)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
android:targetPackage="your.package"
android:label="your tests label" />
and
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Reference: [Android Eclipse Plugin: Instrumentation Test Runner not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified)