# My Android Application is not running

Tags: android

Whenever I try to run my android app it shows the following error .

```
PowerSMS does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml
```

What is the problem ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: how are you trying to run your app?

Comment: By pressing ctrl + F11 , I am trying to run my app .

Comment: I think you can find something from here----> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967632/error-in-android-application-testing       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912939/error-in-android-manifest-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse: Right click->Run As->Android Application instead of Android JUnitTest

Android Studio: Run->Edit Configuration to Run as Android Application either to device or emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably missing the following in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="your.package"
    android:label="your tests label" />
```

and

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```