# Error in Android manifest file

Tags: android

My manifest FILE IS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.Smsr"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.Smsr" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SmsrActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SimpleSmsReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

Error is :**smsr does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml** 
i have two classes here , first is main activity i.e smsrActivity and other is simplesmsreciever class , help me
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think may be ur problem is you have to set minsdk version and target version. Then it will work

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />` in application tag.

for more causes and detailed knowledge check out a previous question
[Android Eclipse Plugin: Instrumentation Test Runner not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified)

Comment: but my app is not starting at all , both on emulator and on phone , nothing happens at all

Comment: your min sdk version is 15 , make sure your emulator and phone is running that or put min sdk version as 10

Comment: i have ics on my phove and all other apps are running

Answer (score 0):

try to run your application as android application. right click your application folder and go down to run as --> android application.

I don't know how or why but this worked with me :)